# How to limit db query data in CakePhp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to limit my db data on CakePhp. It can be limited with find command but I don't know is it possible to limit with my usage. Here is my code from posts_controller.php file:

```
function index() {  
    $this->Post->order = array('order'=>'Post.date DESC','limit'=>5);  
    $this->Post->recursive = 0;  
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$this->paginate['Post'] = array('order'=>array('Post.date DESC'),'limit'=>5,'recursive'=>0);      
$this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
```

For more information see the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/165/Controller-Setup).

Comment: You are great SpawnCxy thank you very much. I am new at CakePhp and/so couldn't understand some basics yet.